# Issue with Developing a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress Collaboration plugin.

In it is a way to create and manage groups.

I have the "add a group" page working great, and am now attempting to create the "edit a group" page.

So I copied the code and html from the "add a group" page, pasted it in to the edit page, and linked to it, the same way I did the add page...

But I am getting

`You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

I am the only admin of the site, it's Wordpress 4.0.  I've gone so far as chmod'ing the files to 777 to no avail.

How can I fix this so it works?

## Page Code for Both Add and Edit

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        /*
        $grpTitle = $_POST['grpTitle'];
        $grpDescription = $_POST['grpDescription'];
        // Create the group
        $wpdb->insert(EMC_GROUP_TABLE, array('gTitle' => $grpTitle, 'gDescription' => $grpDescription), 
                                      array('%s', '%s'));
        $grpID = $wpdb->insert_id;      
        // Insert the selected members
        $grpMember = $_POST['grpMember'];
        $gmCt = count($grpMember);      
        for($gm = 0; $gm < $gmCt; ++$gm){
            $wpdb->insert(EMC_USERS_TABLE, array('groupID' => $grpID, 'userID' => $grpMember[$gm], 'cuType'=>2), 
                                      array('%d', '%d', '%d'));
        }
        // Insert the selected Admins
        $grpAdmins = $_POST['grpAdmins'];
        $aCt = count(grpAdmins);
        for($am = 0; $am < $aCt; ++$am){
            $wpdb->insert(EMC_USERS_TABLE, array('groupID' => $grpID, 'userID' => $grpAdmins[$am], 'cuType'=>1), 
                                      array('%d', '%d', '%d'));
        }
        $grpInclude = $_POST['grpInclude'];
        $giCt = count($grpInclude);
        for($g = 0; $g < $giCt; ++$g){
            $wpdb->insert(EMC_POSTS_TABLE, array('groupID' => $grpID, 'post_id' => $grpInclude[$g]), 
                                      array('%d', '%d', '%d'));
        }
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade" style="padding:10px;">Your group has been created.</div>';
        */
    }
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-widget{font-family:auto;}
    .ui-widget th{font-weight:bold;}
    .tab1{width:24% !important;display:block-inline !important;float:left !important;padding:2px;font-family:inherit;}
    .panel1{background:none !important;border:none !important;}
    .grpSelAll{text-decoration:underline !important;}
    .grpSelAll:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}
</style>
<div class="wrap" style="width:65% !important;">
    <h2><span class="dashicons dashicons-welcome-add-page" style="display:inline-block;padding-top:5px;"></span>&nbsp;Update This Group</h2>
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <form method="post">
        <div id="tabs" class="panel1">
             <ul class="panel1">
                <li class="tab1"><a href="#tabs-1">Main Properties</a></li>
                <li class="tab1"><a href="#tabs-2">Group Members</a></li>
                <li class="tab1"><a href="#tabs-3">Page/Post Permissions</a></li>
                <li class="tab1"><a href="#tabs-4">Group Administrators</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1" class="group-panel panel1">
                <h2>Main Properties</h2>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <h3>
                            <label for="grpTitle">Group Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="grpTitle" id="grpTitle" required />
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <h3>
                        <label for="grpDescription">Group Description</label>
                        <textarea rows="6" style="width:100%;" name="grpDescription" id="grpDescription"></textarea>
                    </h3>           
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2" class="group-panel panel1">
                <h2>Group Members</h2>
                <?php
                    // Grab all users with the proper permissions from WP (not admins)
                    $uc = new EM_Collaboration_Users;
                    $u = $uc->get_wp_allowed_users();
                    $uCt = count($u);
                    if($uCt > 0){
                        echo '<table id="section-groups" class="wp-list-table widefat">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="grpSelAll" data-rel="grpMember" title="Click to Select/De-Select All">Group Member</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>';
                            for($i=0;$i<$uCt;++$i){
                                $un = new WP_User($u[$i]->ID);
                                $uL = $un->roles[0];
                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>' . $u[$i]->display_name . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $u[$i]->user_email . '</td>
                                    <td>' . ucwords($uL) . '</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="grpMember' . $u[$i]->ID . '" name="grpMember[]" value="' . $u[$i]->ID . '" /></td>
                                </tr>';
                            }
                            echo '  </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>  
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="grpSelAll" data-rel="grpMember" title="Click to Select/De-Select All">Group Member</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<p class="error" style="padding:10px;">There are no users with the correct permissions.<br />You will not be able to create this group until you have at least 1 user with proper permissions.</p>';
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3" class="group-panel panel1" style="background:none !important;border:none !important;">
                <h2>Page/Post Permissions</h2>
                <?php
                    $pc = new EM_Collaboration_Posts();
                    $pub_posts = $pc->get_allowed_public_posts();
                    $ppCt = count($pub_posts);
                    if($ppCt > 0){
                        echo '<table id="section-groups" class="wp-list-table widefat">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="grpSelAll" data-rel="grpInclude" title="Click to Select/De-Select All">Include In Group?</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>';
                            for($p=0;$p<$ppCt;++$p){
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>' . $pub_posts[$p]['POST'] . '</td>
                                    <td>' . ucwords($pub_posts[$p]['TYPE']) . '</td>
                                    <td>' . ucwords($pub_posts[$p]['STATUS']) . '</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="grpInclude' . $pub_posts[$p]['ID'] . '" name="grpInclude[]" value="' . $pub_posts[$p]['ID'] . '" /></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                            echo '  </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="grpSelAll" data-rel="grpInclude" title="Click to Select/De-Select All">Include In Group?</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>';          
                    }else{
                        echo '<p class="error" style="padding:10px;">There are no public posts/pages yet.</p>';
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-4" class="group-panel panel1" style="background:none !important;border:none !important;">
                <h2>Group Administrators</h2>
                <?php
                    // Grab all administrators from WP
                    $a = $uc->get_wp_admins();
                    $aCt = count($a);
                    if($aCt > 0){
                        echo '<table id="section-groups" class="wp-list-table widefat">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Joined On</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="grpSelAll" data-rel="grpAdmins" title="Click to Select/De-Select All">Group Admin</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>';
                        for($i=0;$i<$aCt;++$i){
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '  <td>' . $a[$i]->display_name . '</td>';
                            echo '  <td>' . $a[$i]->user_email . '</td>';
                            echo '  <td>' . date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($a[$i]->user_registered)) . '</td>';
                            echo '  <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="grpAdmins' . $a[$i]->ID . '" name="grpAdmins[]" value="' . $a[$i]->ID . '" /></td>';
                            echo '</tr>';                   
                        }
                        echo '  </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Joined On</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="grpSelAll" data-rel="grpAdmins" title="Click to Select/De-Select All">Group Admin</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>';              
                    }else{
                        echo '<p class="error" style="padding:10px;">There are no administrators.</p>';                 
                    }
                ?>
            </div> 
            <div style="display:block;float:right;">
                <?php submit_button('Update This Group', 'primary large'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>   
</div>
 <script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
    jQuery('.grpSelAll').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $which = jQuery(this).attr('data-rel');
        var checkBoxes = jQuery("input[id^=" + $which + "]");
    checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    });
});
</script>
```

## Main Plugin File

```
<?php defined('ABSPATH') or die("No script kiddies please!");
/*
    Plugin Name: My Collaboration
    Version: 0.0.1
    Author: My Communications ~ Kevin C. Pirnie
    Author URI: http://www.arealsite.com
    Description: Collaborate pages and posts with other group members.  Allows for revisioning selection, emailed changes, member permissions on a per post/page basis, works with custom post/page types.
    @author Kevin C. Pirnie <kevin@pirnie.us>

     Copyright 2014 My Communications  (email: kevin@pirnie.us)

*/
// Show all errors
// Report all PHP errors

// error_reporting(-1);
// ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


// Plugin Wide Constants
global $wpdb;
define('EMC_PLUGIN_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
define('EMC_GROUP_TABLE', $wpdb->prefix . "em_collab_groups");
define('EMC_USERS_TABLE', $wpdb->prefix . "em_collab_users");
define('EMC_POSTS_TABLE', $wpdb->prefix . "em_collab_posts");
define('EM_OPTION_GROUP', 'em_options_group');
define('EM_OPTION_ENABLE_MAIL', 'em_email_enable');
define('EM_OPTION_ALLOWED_POST_TYPES', 'em_allowed_post_types');
define('EM_OPTION_EMAIL_DRAFTS', 'em_email_drafts');

if(!class_exists('EM_Collaboration')) {

    // The main plugin class
    class EM_Collaboration {    

            public function __construct(){
                // add in the admin menu items, only for an administrative user
                add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_init'));
                add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_menu'));            
            }

            // On Activating the plugin
            public static function em_activate(){   
                global $wpdb;               
                // Add in our tables if they are needed
                $em_posts = EMC_POSTS_TABLE;
                $em_groups = EMC_GROUP_TABLE;
                $em_users = EMC_USERS_TABLE;
                if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$em_users'") != $em_users) {
                    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$em_users` (
                                `cuID` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                                `groupID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                `userID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                `cuType` int(11) NOT NULL,
                                `cuSettings` longtext NOT NULL,
                                `cuCreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                `cuUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (`cuID`),
                                KEY `groupID` (`groupID`),
                                KEY `userID` (`userID`),
                                KEY `cuType` (`cuType`)
                            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
                    // Create the table
                    dbDelta($sql);
                }
                if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$em_posts'") != $em_posts) {
                    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$em_posts` (
                                `cpID` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                                `groupID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                `cpSettings` longtext NOT NULL,
                                `cpCreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                `cpUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (`cpID`),
                                KEY `groupID` (`groupID`),
                                KEY `post_id` (`post_id`)
                            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
                    // Create the table
                    dbDelta($sql);
                }
                if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$em_groups'") != $em_groups) {
                    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$em_groups` (
                                `groupID` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                                `gTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                                `gDescription` longtext NOT NULL,
                                `gSettings` longtext NOT NULL,
                                `gCreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                `gUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (`groupID`)
                            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
                    // Create the table
                    dbDelta($sql);
                }
            }

            public static function em_deactivate(){
                delete_option(EMC_OPTIONS);     
            }

            // Initialize the administration            
            public function admin_init(){
                // Include necessary classes to do all the work
                require_once(EMC_PLUGIN_PATH . '/classes/em.class.emails.php');
                require_once(EMC_PLUGIN_PATH . '/classes/em.class.group.php');
                require_once(EMC_PLUGIN_PATH . '/classes/em.class.posts.php');
                require_once(EMC_PLUGIN_PATH . '/classes/em.class.users.php');
                require_once(EMC_PLUGIN_PATH . '/classes/em.class.settings.php');
                // Include some needed scripts
                wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
                wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
                wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
                // Include the admin styles
                wp_enqueue_style('dashicons');
                // Register our custom settings
                register_setting(EM_OPTION_GROUP, EM_OPTION_ENABLE_MAIL);
                register_setting(EM_OPTION_GROUP, EM_OPTION_ALLOWED_POST_TYPES);
                register_setting(EM_OPTION_GROUP, EM_OPTION_EMAIL_DRAFTS);
            }

            // Add the menu, only for administrators            
            public function add_menu(){
                if(is_admin()){
                    // Top Menu Item                    
                    add_menu_page(__('EM Collaboration All Groups', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  __('EM Collaboration', 'em-collaboration'), NULL, 'em-collab-top', NULL, '', 21);             
                    // Inner Items                  
                    add_submenu_page('em-collab-top', 
                                          __('EM Collaboration All Groups', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                          __('All Groups', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                          'manage_options', 
                                          'em-collaboration/interface/em-main.php');                                      
                    add_submenu_page('em-collab-top', 
                                          __('Add a New EM Collaboration Group', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                          __('Add New Group', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                          'manage_options', 
                                          'em-collaboration/interface/em-add-group.php');                                     
                    add_submenu_page('em-collab-top', 
                                          __('EM Collaboration Settings', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                          __('Settings', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                          'manage_options', 
                                          'em-collaboration/interface/em-settings.php');
                }
            }
    }

    // Installation hook
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('EM_Collaboration', 'em_activate'));
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('EM_Collaboration', 'em_deactivate'));
    // instantiate the plugin class
    $em_collaboration_plugin = new EM_Collaboration();
    if(isset($em_collaboration_plugin)) {
        function plugin_settings_link($links) { 
            return $links; 
        }
        $plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__); 
        add_filter("plugin_action_links_$plugin", 'plugin_settings_link');
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you remove the plugin?

Comment: ?  No.  I did de-activate, re-activate though

Comment: If it's activated and there is faulty code, that could be why you are getting the error.

Comment: Faulty code where though?  the add page works without issue, the same exact code is in the edit page, yet it throws the error...

Comment: please post your code

Comment: for? the page(s)? the plugin? what?

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote, or are people just fasicious?

Comment: the linked code is for the edit page, is that edit page a template for front end? or a backend page? if it's a backend page, how do you include it? are you using any of this hooks? http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus to add a page in backend you have to use a hook, you can't just reference it. You can pastebin the code of your plugin (if it's open source/free) so we can have a look...

Comment: It is for the edit page, and the add page.  Backend page, no hooks, just link to it like I do the add page via `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=em-collaboration/interface/em-add-group.php` and `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=em-collaboration/interface/em-edit-group.php`   The difference is, the add works, the edit does not

Comment: @alexalex is correct. You need to register the settings page somehow. I'm surprised you can even access the "add" page.

Comment: You're not showing the relevant code to answer the question.

Comment: @rnevius & @ alexalex  I do have the add page added to the main plugin file itself?  Is that what you mean?  If so, I was under the impression that adding it there would make it appear in the admin menu (the left column one) which is not what I want...  I'll post that code too in a minute

Comment: 4 downvotes with no explenation as to why... love that

Comment: As I stated in the question the edit file is an exact copy of the add page posted, since it is a duplicate, I will not duplicate the code in the question

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

`add_menu_page(__('EM Collaboration All Groups', 'em-collaboration'), __('EM Collaboration', 'em-collaboration'), NULL, 'em-collab-top', NULL, '', 21);`

to:

`add_menu_page(__('EM Collaboration All Groups', 'em-collaboration'), __('EM Collaboration', 'em-collaboration'), 'manage_options', 'em-collab-top', NULL, '', 21);`

The third argument in this function is asking for the capability required to access the page, you had it set to null, which is not a valid capability.

Also in the add_menu function you have everything wrapped in is_admin(). This is not needed, and doesn't work the way it may sound. It isn't checking if the current user is an administrator, it is checking if the screen being viewed is in the wp-admin area. Which all admin pages of course are by nature.

Comment: Gives the same error, and there is now a EM Collaboration item in the menu http://prntscr.com/55bzfj   On using the original line of code: http://prntscr.com/55bzrf

Answer (score -1):

Is your Edit page is separate page or you have include that page in some other page. Also if you want to have new submenu for the edit page then you need to create a new submenu for that. Also if you can send us the URL of the page where you are getting this error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."  then i can able to tell you more about your issue. Basically this type of error is caused if you are trying to access a resource which wasn't there.

Thanks